# Pandas dataframe multiple groupby filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'season':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],'value' : [-2, 3,1,5,8,6,7,5], 'test':[3,2,6,8,7,4,25,2],'test2':[4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12]},index=['2020', '2020', '2020','2020', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2021']) 
df2.index=  pd.to_datetime(df2.index)  
df2.index = df2.index.year
print(df2)

        season  test  test2  value
2020       1     3      4     -2
2020       1     2      5      3
2020       1     6      7      1
2020       2     8      8      5
2020       2     7      9      8
2021       2     4     10      6
2021       3    25     11      7
2021       3     2     12      5
```

I would like to filter it to obtain for each year and each season of that year the maximum value of the column 'value'. How can I do that efficiently?

Expected result:

```
print(df_result)

        season  value  test  test2
year                            
2020       1      3     2      5
2020       2      8     7      9
2021       2      6     4     10
2021       3      7     25    11
```

Thank you for your help,

Pierre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can elevate your index to a series, then perform a `groupby` operation on a list of columns:

```
df2['year'] = df2.index
df_result = df2.groupby(['year', 'season'])['value'].max().reset_index()

print(df_result)

   year  season  value
0  2020       1      4
1  2020       2      8
2  2021       2      6
3  2021       3      7
```

If you wish, you can make `year` your index again via `df_result = df_result.set_index('year')`.

To keep other columns use:

```
df2['year'] = df2.index
df2['value'] = df2.groupby(['year', 'season'])['value'].transform('max')
```

Then drop any duplicates via `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`.

#### Update #1

For your new requirement, you need to apply an aggregation function for 2 series:

```
df2['year'] = df2.index

df_result = df2.groupby(['year', 'season'])\
               .agg({'value': 'max', 'test': 'last'})\
               .reset_index()

print(df_result)

   year  season  value  test
0  2020       1      4     6
1  2020       2      8     7
2  2021       2      6     2
3  2021       3      7     2
```

#### Update #2

For your finalised requirement:

```
df2['year'] = df2.index

df2['max_value'] = df2.groupby(['year', 'season'])['value'].transform('max')

df_result = df2.loc[df2['value'] == df2['max_value']]\
               .drop_duplicates(['year', 'season'])\
               .drop('max_value', 1)


print(df_result)

      season  value  test  test2  year
2020       1      3     2      5  2020
2020       2      8     7      9  2020
2021       2      6     4     10  2021
2021       3      7    25     11  2021
```

Comment: In my dataframe I have other columns as well. When applying this technique, all the other columns disappear. Is there a way to keep the other columns as well?

Comment: I have updated the question with a complete example. Any idea how I could do that? Many thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, that's perfect!

Comment: `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'season':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],'value' : [-2, 3,1,5,8,6,7,5], 'test':[3,2,6,8,7,4,25,2],'test2':[4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12]},index=['2020', '2020', '2020','2020', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2021']) 
df2.index=  pd.to_datetime(df2.index)  
df2.index = df2.index.year
df2['year'] = df2.index
df_result = df2.groupby(['year', 'season']).agg({'value': 'max','test':'last','test2': 'last'}).reset_index()
df_result.index = pd.to_datetime(df_result.year,format = '%Y') 
df_result.index = df_result.index.year
df_result.drop(['year'], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: The 'last' option of the agg function takes the last element of the column but not the one that should be selected. How can I keep the rows that correspond to each maximum value of the 'value' column for each year and each season? Is there an agg parameter that is fit to that purpose? Many thanks!

Comment: @Peslier53, You can use `'first'`, `'last'`, `'max'`, `'min'`, etc. It should be intuitive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for replying. I get that, the problem is that there is a relationship that i need to keep between the columns. I have re-edited my question. Basically, when selecting the maximum value of the column 'value' for each year and each season, i want to keep the entire corresponding row of the original dataframe. When applying those arguments cited above, i apply a different process to each column individually which is not what I want.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help provided! Where did you learn all that? Experience only? Do you recommend a good book or any good learning material for manipulating data with pandas? thanks again

Comment: @Peslier53, I learnt by looking at other answers on SO and answering questions myself :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a `groupby` operation, but a little non-trivial, so posting as an answer.

```
(df2.set_index('season', append=True)
    .groupby(level=[0, 1])
    .value.max()
    .reset_index(level=1)
)
      season  value
2020       1      4
2020       2      8
2021       2      6
2021       3      7
```

Comment: In my dataframe I have other columns as well. When applying this technique, all the other columns disappear. Is there a way to keep the other columns as well?

Comment: @Peslier53 I don't know what your other columns are, so I can't tell you what to do or how to fix it.

Comment: Let's assume two more columns: `df2['test']=2`      `df2['test2'] = 5`

Comment: @Peslier53 so what do you want to do? Take the max? Take the first? Last? Sum? mean? You can't do _nothing_, since your result is smaller than the original (so your question isn't clear to me).

Comment: I would like to filter the dataframe to obtain for each year and each season of that year the maximum value of the column 'value'. All rows with the maximum 'value' for each year and each season will be kept (those rows keeping the other values contained in the other columns). I have re-edited the question with an example. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can using `get_level_values` for bring index value into `groupby`

```
df2.groupby([df2.index.get_level_values(0),df2.season]).value.max().reset_index(level=1)
Out[38]: 
      season  value
2020       1      4
2020       2      8
2021       2      6
2021       3      7
```